# Can't install Flask-WTF

Tags: python, flask, installation, pip

Ok so i wanted to get into Flask-WTF but whatever I would try I just can't seem to install it.I'm trying to learn it from a course , in the requirements.txt file i've already added the Flask==2.0.3' 'itsdangerous==2.1.0' 'flask and it doesnt seem to work. Pip installs dont work , the cmd doesnt work and I do not know what to do .
Example of error :
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

```
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install -U Flask-WTF
+ ~~~
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am pretty new to flask and stuff like that so I'm sorry if it's a stupid question. Hope I didn't waste anybody's time.

Comment: If your pip is not recognized, the easiest thing to do is reinstall python while checking the box shown here: https://book.buzzcoder.com/assets/Python_install_options.png which automatically adds it to path variables. Keep in mind you will need to reinstall all pips you have already done. If you are on linux or mac, also try "pip3" instead of "pip." Also, this goes without saying, but make sure the only python installation you have is of the most recent version found from https://python.org.

Answer (score 0):

your term is not recognized. you should setting environment variable thing, look Environement Variables in Advanced system setting. add the path **anaconda**

Comment: Any chance you can edit to be more specific for OP?

Comment: I've tried a bit didn't really work but I might've done something wrong cuz I couldn't really try for hours and hours cuz I have some school stuff to do but I will try a lot more in the weekend. Thank you very much for the response !